# How to take control/cursor to another text box

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts

I have a page where you enter customer-id first and hit submit. That point it will validate the customer and if valid, comes back to the same page to enter quote number. Initially quotenumber field will be grayed out and can not be edited. My question is, after it comes back to the page, I need the cursor to go to the "quote number" text box instead of customer-id text box (currently it goes to customer-id text box). How can I solve this?

Comment: How do you set the cursor to the customer-id box?  an Onload call?

Comment: no. I do using "focus " like this :                             <html:form action="/re/Confirm" focus="customer-id">

Answer (score 0):

use javascript's focus() function or jQuery

Answer (score -1):

in jquery it would be

```
 $("#myinput").focus();
```